# accessing picture box on activated childform, c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an MDI application where i want to access a picturebox on my activated childform.
Surprissingly I can't access the picturebox control.

Here is the code:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Determine the active child form.
  Form activeChild = this.ActiveMdiChild;
  PictureBox mypic = (PictureBox) activeChild...; // cannot see picturebox
}
```

In childform:

```
public PictureBox picbox
{
   get
   {
     return pictureBox1;
   }
   set
   {
     pictureBox1 = value;
   }
}
```

Where is my issue?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`activeChild` refers to the whole MDI child.

You are using a `Form` type which will not have `picbox` defined on it - you should either use the correct class type of the child form, or cast the reference to the right type.

Additionally - you only need to access the `picbox` property (which is already the right type, so no need to cast):

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Determine the active child form.
  ChildForm activeChild = this.ActiveMdiChild as ChildForm;
  if(activeChild != null)
  {
    PictureBox mypic = ((ChildFormClass)activeChild).picbox;
    ...
  }
}
```

OR:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Determine the active child form.
  Form activeChild = this.ActiveMdiChild;
  PictureBox mypic = ((ChildFormClass)activeChild).picbox;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Form class doesn't have a property named "picbox".  Only your custom designed form does.  Make your code look similar to this:

```
  Form2 activeChild = this.ActiveMdiChild as Form2;
  if (activeChild != null) {
     PictureBox mypic = activeChild.picbox;
     // etc...
  }
```

Where "Form2" is the type name of your form class.